# Zoom H2n announced!

Tags: h2n, zoom, portable-recorder

...well as i told you in my earlier post today (http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/9245/zoom-h4n-adoration-post) I can call myself a happy user of my new H4N that arrived today!

and when I got to the official site to download the firmware update I found this one! http://zoom.co.jp/products/h2n . I guess many of you guys might be interested.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! It has built MS mic!

An excellent opportunity for beginner to try new mic technique!

Answer (score 1):

Interested to see the quality of five mics in there. Would be a great pocket recorder for a cool ambiance or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that will definitely be a buy for me. I love that it's black, cause it makes you even more inconspicuous in places where it could be fishy to be recording, like public spaces where people could get upset or stuff like that,  and the recording capabilities of course. And price! Yummy :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a nifty little device for use by reporters, podcasters, researchers and the like.  The size and battery life are certainly a big draw-card. I believe Zoom have done their homework, as the H2N and H4N are clearly targeting two different market niches. Most of the people on SSD will still opt for the H4N for two reasons:

1) Combo XLR inputs allow for much more versatility in terms of mic selection and placement.

2) The accessory pack that is included with the H4N is an extra for the H2N, so the $100 saving is pretty much negated anyway.

Comment: One thing doesn't have to cancel the other :) I'd go for both!

Answer (score 0):

The MS in it, is a hit. COOL

Comment: have you tried it Muks?

Comment: No, not yet:( Nikos

Answer (score 0):

Anyone know where can it or any pro audio stuff be bought in Vancouver, canada? A friend is going there to see her parents next month. I thought of ordering.

Comment: @Rig There's Tom lee on Granville street